# Check whether a string is contained in a element (list) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe with the column 'Friends'. All elements in the column friends are list object. Example of a row in the column 'friends':

```
['erik', 'jason', 'eduard']
```

I want to return a dataframe in which I check whether eduard is the list. This is my example code:

```
df[df.friends.isin(['eduard'])
```

Help a cat out please

Answer (score 8):

You need `apply` in this case, use the normal `in` operator to check if list contains `eduard`:

```
df[df.friends.apply(lambda x: 'eduard' in x)]
```

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"friends": [['erik', 'jason', 'eduard'], ['erik', 'jason']]})

df[df.friends.apply(lambda x: 'eduard' in x)]
#                 friends
#0  [erik, jason, eduard]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This question also came in class and I remember  simpler answer, something with .str.isin. Could that also be used?

Comment: @JanKlaas Not with a column of lists.

Comment: You can use `isin` if you have a normal column and want to check if the items in the column is in another list.

Comment: what if I have a list and I want to check if any of item from the list in the string?

Answer (score 1):

you can use sets intersection:

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]:
                 friends
0  [erik, jason, eduard]
1            [anna, max]
2       [eduard, natali]

In [67]: df[df.friends.map(set) & {'anna','natali'}]
Out[67]:
            friends
1       [anna, max]
2  [eduard, natali]
```